# Change shipping rate based on the weight or volume

Tags: product, shipping, tax, shipping-methods, shipping-tax

I have a question on shipping. Is possible to set a method that takes the volume or weight of the product and calculate the cost depending on a scale?

Answer (score 2):

Try **Table Rates** shipping method.
Their you have an option as per your need.

If you want to do some custom calculation you can make use of the `checkout_cart_save_before` event.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the table rates. Admin -system - configuration - shipping methods - table rates.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento admin go to:
System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Shipping Method.

Open The Table Rates section and select "Weight vs Destination" value for Condition

[image]

Export the file and save it to your PC. Open the file with a text editor, or using Excel and add the lines you want. At the end, the file you have created should look like this one:

```
Paese,Regione/Stato,"Zip/Codice postale","Peso (e superiore)","Prezzo spedizione"
"IT","*","*","0","5.90"
"IT","*","*","10","7.90"
"IT","*","*","25","9.90"
```

Upload the file using the "Browse..." button and save the Configuration. If everything is ok, you should see a green line informing you that the file was imported siccessfully.

Comment: Could you perhaps set your Magento Admin to English and replace the Italian examples with English examples?

Comment: Here's the file exported with english header:
`
Country,Region/State,"Zip/Postal Code","Weight (and above)","Shipping Price"

ITA,*,*,0.0000,5.9000

ITA,*,*,10.0000,7.9000

ITA,*,*,25.0000,9.9000

`